# postgresql load sql script

Tags: postgresql

I want to load and execute a sql file from another sql file, but do not the syntax. Is this possible? In detail, I have a file install_tables.sql which should load a file tables_definition.sql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run your script using `psql` you can embedd the `\i` command in your main script:

```
 \i tables_defininition.sql
```